# Can I create a browser bookmarklet to automatically create a new copy of a Google Sheets doc to be used as template?

Tags: google-sheets, bookmarklet

I want to create a custom template that will contain a number of macros saved, so that each new sheet doc I create has already embedded this macros.

I currently have a bookmark in my browser bar linking to sheets.new, which creates a blank spreadsheet. I would like to have this behavior but with a copy of an existing doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your goal is somewhat similar to this [Share “Make a copy” links to your files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308866?hl=en).

**What you need to do:**

1. Open the template file
2. Get the file link in the address bar
3. Replace edit -> copy (you can remove trailing characters as well)
4. Go to the link and bookmark it

---

**Example Copy Document Link:**

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e6ufPtdssEqmhn8SS_L5HsRNRbPIlCdtrp2D1xxxx/copy
```

**Note:**

Once you go to the copy link, you still need to click the `Make Copy` button before you can create a copy of your template file

---

**Sample:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want new sheet on the go use:

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create**